# How to generate distinct random numbers per distinct threads in .NET?

Tags: .net, multithreading, random

I have to generate 19 bit random numbers. However, there is a constraint - two threads may not generate the same random number when running certain code.

The simplest solution is lock the entire code. However, I would like to know if there is a non locking solution. I thought, I can incorporate ManagedThreadId within the produced random numbers, but the ManagedThreadId documentation on the Internet mentions that it may span the whole Int32 range. Unmanaged thread id seems to be limited to 11 bits, still this leaves me with just 8 truly random bits.

Are there any other ways? Somehow to utilize the Thread Local Storage, may be?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I wish to clear something. The random numbers may repeat, this is inevitable, eventually. What I wish to avoid is if a certain piece of code is simultaneously entered by two threads, then these threads may not use the same random number, guaranteed. Before or after that code is executed - fine, but not within the code itself. Again, I can use some locking scheme to prevent it, but I want to examine non locking schemes first.

**EDIT 2**

Reading the comments/answers to my question I have understood that I cannot avoid but to lock the particular code. However, for the sake of pure academic curiosity, I am still interested to know if anyone knows a good solution to my original question - generating 19 bits random numbers in multiple threads, where the numbers are guaranteed to be distinct between threads, given that the ManagedThreadId can be potentially very large, so large that simply aggregating it within the random number is bad - leaves no space for the actual random bits.

Comment: Please elaborate on the constraint and needs: do you mean to constantly create new random numbers on each thread, in a way that the two threads cannot create the same random number?

Comment: There are only 2**19 numbers that are 19 bits. If you need to generate more than that many numbers, it does not matter how many or few threads you have or how you partition these numbers: you'll have repeats.

Answer (score 2):

Well how many threads are you actually going to use? That's the limiting factor. If you only need (say) 8 threads then you can just lose 3 bits of information. You could create a "generator factory" which knows how many generators it's *allowed* to create, and throws an exception if you try to create too many.

Your requirement for distinct numbers isn't very clear though - even if you make sure that one thread never creates the same number that another thread has created, you still have to worry about whether you create a duplicate number *on the same thread*. Is that a problem for you or not?

Comment: This is a server application. Requests come in and out all the time. So the likely pattern is that there are a few threads active all the time, but these are not the same threads every time.

Comment: @mark: So what exactly are you requirements around threading? It doesn't sound like threads are the right way to think about your uniqueness requirements, IMO.

Comment: I interpreted your solution in a comment on my answer.  Want to give you the opportunity to check my interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

Use thread-local storage to hold a reference to a `System::Random` object. Give each thread its own RNG (you can tell easily enough if you've not yet allocated one) and you can pull values from each one merrily for as long as you like. It's probably a good idea to wrap up the code to get a thread-specific random number in a method so that you only need to get it right once.

---

[Edit: Include example]

```
class example {
    [ThreadStatic]
    static Random threadLocalRandom;
    private int GimmeARandomNumber(int upperBound) {
        Random r = threadLocalRandom;
        if (r == null) {
            r = threadLocalRandom = new Random();
        }
        return r.Next(0, upperBound);
    }
}
```

Comment: The overall scheme is understood. It is the details which I am interested in. Can you share the details?

Comment: See updated version and be aware that I hardly ever write C# so it could have horrible blunders.

Comment: Note that if you start two threads with this method at almost the same time, they will generate the same random sequence. You should initialize the Random object with an explicit seed value

Comment: Sure, but that's pretty easy to layer on top in a performant way given that the bulk load of managing random number generation doesn't have problems with locks.

Answer (score 1):

If you really can never repeat a number between threads or in the same thread (that part isn't 100% clear), a regular random number generator will not work for you.  A generator that creates a number between 1 and N has a 1-in-N chance of generating the previous number the next time it's asked for one.

If there's an reasonable upper limit on the total number of random numbers, call it N, for a particular run, you might consider creating an array from 1 to N.  Sequentially populate that array with numbers from 1 to N, and then use a [shuffling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Shuffling_algorithms) to sort the numbers.  If you have M threads, you could then segment the shuffled array such that the first thread uses indices 0, M, 2M; the second thread uses indices 1, M+1, 2M+1, etc. ensuring you don't access past the end of the shuffled array.

This is a memory intensive solution for fairly large N, so may not be appropriate for your problem.  If you are allowed to repeat the same random number on a given thread, just not between threads, Jon's solution is much more resource friendly.

Comment: I have updated the question. Basically, there is certain code, which does not tolerate same random numbers on the different threads. In all other places, the random numbers may be the same.

Comment: I do not see it this way. Jon's solution is to integrate the thread Id (or index) within the random number, which is fine if the thread Id (or index) is bounded by a small number of bits. However, ManagedThreadId is int and unmanaged thread id can still be 11 bits long. Having a custom thread count may seem a good idea, but as threads are created and disposed, the count goes higher and higher until it requires many bits to represent it. So, this naive approach is no good in the general case.

Comment: @Mark: I interpret Jon's approach to mean have a factory that returns a generator and uses an internal counter for the 3 (or so) bits you're willing to give up to identify the thread.  There would be a 1:1 relationship between the managed thread Id and that internal counter, but the internal counter would start at zero and increment by one each time the factory is asked to return a new generator.

Comment: @Eric, That is what I mean by thread index. It starts from zero and is assigned to the new thread. Although the total number of threads at any given moment may be limited, these are not the same threads as at the start of the application. The thread index is incremented with each new thread (cheap using Interlocked.Increment) At the end, this thread index may occupy too many bits, leaving only a few for the random bits themselves. BTW, random numbers may coincide within the same thread, this I am not going to avoid.

Comment: @Mark: The same way a connection pool re-uses a limited set of DB connections, the factory could re-use a limited set of threads (thread pool).  The upper limit could be dictated by the number of bits you're willing to dedicate to the thread index.  Of course you would need a mechanism to return threads to the pool once no longer needed for a given operation.